# Visual Studio 2008: No Build Events folder on the project Properties page

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, post-build-event

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional to build a VB.NET console application. I have a text file that I want to copy to the output directory after a build. I would like to create a build event to do that, but I do not see a "Build Events" folder on the property page. Is there a setting where I can get this folder? Or, is there another way I can set up a post-build event to copy a file to the output directory?

The folders I see on the Properties page: 
Application
Compile
Debug
References
Resources
Services
Settings
Signing
My Extensions
Security
Publish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile tab.  Scroll down and right, click the Build Events button.

But, no need to do it that way, just add it to your project with Project + Add Existing Item.  Select it and in the Property window set Build Action to "Content" if you want it deployed, Copy to Output to "Copy if newer".

Comment: I didn't even think to scroll in that window. Thanks for the answer. And also thanks for the tip about the Build Action and Copy to Output